# I am getting a segmentation fault in my code

Tags: c, cs50

I am writing a code that reads information from a memory card (card.raw is the one we are provided but the code uses user input) and extracts the jpegs from it using the signatures that jpegs have of (0xff,0xd8,0xff,0x00 - 0xff). I am getting a segmentation fault because i am using malloc, but i dont see where i went wrong. I am pasting my code here any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //check terminal usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image");
        return 1;
    }

    //open inputted file and check for valid file
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Invalid or missing file.");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE *buff = malloc(512 * sizeof(BYTE));
    int counter = 0;
    FILE *image = NULL;
    char *name = malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    //loop till end of file reached and read a block of input
    while(fread(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, file) == 1 && !feof(file))
    {
        bool foundJPEG = buff[0] == 0xff && buff[1] == 0xd8 && buff[2] == 0xff && ((buff[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0);

        //check if found jpeg, and open file for writing
        if (foundJPEG)
        {
            sprintf(name, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            image = fopen(name, "w");
        }
        //if image file open, write to it
        if (image != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(buff, sizeof(BYTE), 512, image);
        }
        //if found a jpeg already, close it so new one can be written
        if (foundJPEG && image != NULL)
        {
            fclose(image);
            counter++;
        }

    }

    free(name);
    free(buff);
    fclose(image);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes as and when they happen, and how to locate where they happen in your code, and to examine variables and their values at that point. The logic in your loop seems a bit off as well, I suggest you also do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or just use a debugger to step through the code, statement by statement, to make sure that it does what's intended.

Comment: And I really don't see any need for your dynamic allocation. All your dynamic allocations could be replaced with simple arrays.

Comment: You're not allowed to call `fclose` on a file that's already closed, or on `NULL`.

Comment: Also, `while(fread(buff, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, file) == 1 && !feof(file))` looks wrong.

Comment: True. The `fread` should return a value `> 0` which should be assigned to a variable, so that you know how many items to write (which may be less than requested). It is unlikely to be `1` (here) except for the last block.

Comment: It is also wrong to call `feof()` here. If you attempt to read `512` bytes but there are only `10` unread bytes in the file, `feof()` will return a non-zero value, but you *want* those `10` bytes. Use the actual number of items read to control the loop. `while((size_t bytesread = fread(buff, 512, 1, file)) > 0) { ... }`.

Comment: I think your seg fault come from the size of ```name```. To represent a string correctly it should end with NULL char. Try extended it's length by one and put NULL in last char

Comment: `sprintf` will place a `NUL` terminator, and it's better to be more generous with the string size anyway. Don't make it `9` make it `100`, and it is quite unecessary to use `malloc` for that. `char name[100];` won't need to be `free`d later.

Comment: Using `stdio.h` may be a valid approach at an evaluation stage. However, the question was about extracting jpg images from a sd card, which is a blockdevice. Therefore you should think of basing your code on `dio.h`, instead. Then you can read one block after each other from the card circumventing the file system when you determined the blocksize beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with the code above which are not mentioned in the comments:

The return value of `fread` is not 1 but 512, upon successful read. You exchanged the parameters for the blocksize and the blockcount -> [fread definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/). Therefore the while loop is not entered.
Don't try to save space with packing to much code into one statement. If would be more clever to separate the checks for the `fread` return value and the EOF and use a `do ... while()` loop, instead. Then you had the chance of seeing this issue in the debugger. This was exactly what i have done and how i found this out.

The second issue is that you close the image after rescuing the first 512 bytes, but you do not reset the file pointer `image` back to `NULL` along with the `fclose` statement.
As a consequence, the code would repeatedly write to an a file which is closed until a new block with a jpg header is found.

The third issue is that you only rescue the first 512 bytes of the jpg but not the whole jpg. You need to scan the input stream for the jpg end indicator `FF D9` and copy bytes until it is found. ->[jpg format](https://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm)